# NHibernate está modificando propriedade ao retornar pelo Web Api

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate

Tenho um serviço web api onde é relalizado uma consulta ao banco através do nhibernate, mas ao retornar o objeto, suas propriedades referenciadas são sobrescritas, creio q seja por causa do proxy do nhibernate.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso estar fazendo para corrigir este problema?

Segue as classes PessoaClinica e depois Pessoa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor e colocar o código de onde o problema ocorre. Eu não posso ajudar se eu não conseguir reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Boa tarde @MiguelAngelo o exemplo é bem simples de reproduzir, tenho uma classe PessoaClinica e dentro dela tenha uma propriedade do tipo Pessoa, onde contém todas as propriedades referentes a pessoa.
Estou utilizando o NHibernate para fazer conexão com o banco de dados, quando retorno o objeto PessoaClinica atraves de um controller web api, no cliente chega conforme a imagem acima, o correto era Pessoa conter somente as propriedades que estão dentro de _target.

Comment: Acabei de colocar umas imagens da classe PessoaClinica e da classe Pessoa, veja se agora fica mais claro. Estou fazendo uma consulta de PessoaClinica e no retorno no cliente fica conforme a primeira imagem.

Comment: Como está fazendo mapeamento de classes: tá usando FluentNHibernate, a sintaxe fluent do próprio NHibernate ou arquivo XML?

Comment: Estou utilizando fluentNHibernate, com structureMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você bem suspeitou o culpado é o Proxy do NHibernate. Não acho que seja uma boa ideia serializar o objeto proxy exatamente pelo fato de se ter pouco controle sobre o mesmo.

Algumas opções:

- informar o NHibernate para não usar proxy no mapeamento da propriedade `Pessoa`:

  ```
  this.References(x => x.Pessoa)
      .Not.LazyLoad();
  ```
- usar um objeto clonado do original, para isso você pode usar a biblioteca [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

  ```
  // inicialização do AutoMapper
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
  {
      cfg.CreateMap<PessoaClinica, PessoaClinica>();
      cfg.CreateMap<Pessoa, Pessoa>();
  });
  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

  // usando no controller
  Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
  PessoaClinica obj = ...; // obter o objeto do banco de dados
  return mapper.Map<PessoaClinica, PessoaClinica>(obj);
  ```

  Nota: provavelmente você vai querer injetar dependência da variável `mapper`
- usar um objeto especializado (DTO) e copiar as propriedades uma a uma, sendo que você retornaria a DTO ao invés do proxy de dentro do método da WebAPI. Também é possível usar o AutoMapper nessa opção.
- Customizar o processo de serialização... isso seria usar um canhão para matar mosca

Comment: Deu certo, porém tive que utilizar o Dto, quando usei o AutoMapper com a mesma classe, deu na mesma, mas utilizando o Dto deu certo.

Comment: Realmente, você teria de implementar um conversor customizado, pois não basta clonar o próprio objeto, tem que clonar recursivamente. Vou editar só pra resposta não ficar incompleta.

Comment: Errei... na verdade tem que configurar para clonar a classe `Pessoa` também, ... o que eu esqueci de fazer.